# Creating a clickable tooltip in javascript or bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

What is the best way to make a clickable tooltip like the one in the picture below:

[image]

Should I use bootstrap or some other library?

Thanks.

Comment: bootstrap is cool: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: bootstrap's popovers are even better: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: Can you expand upon what you expect the widget to do?

Comment: I want a hover event or click event on the Postsecondary div and then the blue popunder/tooltip to appear. Then the Students or Faculty is also clickable. And lastly if you don't hover over the blue part, it disappears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here You go

```js
$("#Pops").popover({
html: true,
content: function () {
    return $('#popover-content').html();
}
});
```

```css
[data-style=mypops] + .popover {
background: #4194ca;
}
[data-style=mypops] + .popover.bottom .arrow:after {
border-bottom-color: #4194ca;
}
[data-style=mypops] + .popover-content {
}
.popovermenu {
list-style: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
.popovermenu li {
}
.popovermenu li a {
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <button tabindex="0" class="btn btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" data-style="mypops" id="Pops">Click Me</button>
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
      <ul class="popovermenu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

- Added custom `data-style="mypops"` in popover button and add in css so popover can be customized without effecting the default popover in bootstrap.
- Replaced `data-trigger="click"` with `data-trigger="focus"` in popover button so if click one a link or outside the popover window, popover will be auto closed.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6L9j0v5y/1/)

Comment: how do you get the styles to look like that? my copy just shows the lists

Comment: if you used the same code from answer, shouldn't be a problem unless you made any change in it or you are not using bootstrap framework, can you provide a snap shot?

Answer (score 8):

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger: "manual" , html: true, animation:false})
    .on("mouseenter", function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
<a href="#" role="button" class="btn popovers" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="test content <a href='https://www.w3schools.com' title='test add link'>link on content</a>" data-original-title="test title">test link</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the Timer do in MouseLeave?

Comment: @geneb Checks that the pointer is within the tooltip or not after 300ms, if not then the tooltip is hidden I reckon

Comment: during the mouseenter event you create a new event handler.  this could lead to a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap's popover and use the template option to include clickable links in your tooltip. There are also options regarding the tooltip's position.

```
$(function (){
    $("#example").popover({
        template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
        placement: 'right'
    });  
});
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options