# How to give link inside the tooltip(not pop over) and when we hover over the button we should able to click on the same

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have given a tooltip over a button, and I have also provided link on the text when we hover over the button, but I am not able to click on the link.

and I have given link to the whole text, but I want to give to the particular section,

here is my html and bootstrap code:

```
<a disabled data-html="true"
    style="float:right !important;"
    class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right"
    href="https://www.google.com"
    data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true"
    title="<a href='https://www.google.com' target='blank'>Print feature is enabled for subscription users. Sign up Today<a href="https://www.talentinsights.com/contact-us/">Print Result Summary</a>
```

Comment: You have an anchor tag in your title attribute.

Comment: should i replaced it to button ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a clickable tooltip in javascript or bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000298/creating-a-clickable-tooltip-in-javascript-or-bootstrap)

Comment: title should be text only

Comment: tooltip is working with anchor tag only

Comment: @NickParsons No that popup will not work , my button is disabled and i want to show data on hover only

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem:

```
<span class="d-inline-block pull-right btn-sm pull-right" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="
                                   Print feature is enabled for subscription users.<a href='www.google.com'> Sign up Today</a>">
                                    Print Result Summary
                                </button>
                            </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something the direction of the following approach:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            p.myTooltip {
                display: none;
                background-color: yellow;
                padding: 10px;
                margin-top: -5px;
                z-index: 10;
                position: relative;
                opacity: 0.8;
            }

            div:hover p.myTooltip {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Hover me and see" />
            <p class="myTooltip">
                Tada here I am <a href="https://www.google.com">Google me</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```