# Select Day or Month or Year in Single Calendar or DatePicker (Flexible Selection Mode)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I have a unified textbox control where I need to flexibly accept a DatePicker selection which can be one of the following 3: Day (MM/DD/YYYY), Month (MM/YYYY), OR Year (YYYY).

I'm using Bootstrap DatePicker which has `startView` and `minViewMode` but the only thing I was able to do is separate them into 3 separate controls which isn't what I want. My goal is a combined control.

Here's the script I'm starting out with. Maybe I can create some invisible DatePickers and toggle them with a custom extra button, such as "Select This Level"? Or maybe I can hack the DatePicker panel to add a row of radiobuttons, "Day" / "Month" / "Year" which will switch the viewMode dynamically?

```js
$('#day').datepicker({
     format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
     autoclose: true, 
    startView: "days", 
    minViewMode: "days"     
}).on('change', function (ev) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

$('#month').datepicker({
     format: "mm/yyyy",
     autoclose: true, 
    startView: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
}).on('change', function (ev) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

$('#year').datepicker({
     format: "yyyy",
     autoclose: true, 
    startView: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
}).on('change', function (ev) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



Day Picker: <input id="day"> <br/>
Month Picker: <input id="month"> <br/>
Year Picker: <input id="year"> <br/>
COMBINED Day OR Month OR Year Picker Picker: <input id="combined" placeholder="Can get MM/DD/YYYY, MM/YYYY, or YYYY" style="width:250px"> <br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a popover with three buttons(or whatever style you want) and show the datepicker depending on the one that is clicked. Took the popover code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52552171/5773530).

```js
$('#Pops').datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  startView: "days",
  minViewMode: "days"
})
  .on('change', function(ev) {
      $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });

function showDatePicker(type) {
  let picker = {
    day: {
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
      autoclose: true,
      startView: "days",
      minViewMode: "days"
    },
    month: {
      format: "mm/yyyy",
      autoclose: true,
      startView: "months",
      minViewMode: "months"
    },
    year: {
      format: "yyyy",
      autoclose: true,
      startView: "years",
      minViewMode: "years"
    }
  };
  console.log('boo', type, picker[type])
  $('#Pops').datepicker("destroy")
  $('#Pops').datepicker(picker[type])
  $('#Pops').datepicker('show')
}

$(document).on("click", ".day", function() {
  showDatePicker('day')
});
$(document).on("click", ".month", function() {
  showDatePicker('month')
});
$(document).on("click", ".year", function() {
  showDatePicker('year')
});

$("#Pops").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover-content').html();
    },
    trigger: 'manual'
  })
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).popover('show');
    $('.popover').on('mouseleave', function() {
      $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!$('.popover:hover').length) {
        $(_this).popover('hide');
      }
    }, 300);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

COMBINED Day OR Month OR Year Picker Picker: <input id="Pops" placeholder="Can get MM/DD/YYYY, MM/YYYY, or YYYY" style="width:250px" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom"> <br/>

<div id="popover-content" class="hide">

  <button class="day">day</button>
  <button class="month">month</button>
  <button class="year">year</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Riddhesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504807/1005607)'s answer I also created a cleaner, simpler radiobutton-controlled mode switch, without a popover.

But just as in his answer, the key idea is (1) destroy the DatePicker, (2) re-initialize with new Options on the fly.

```js
 function setDatePicker(type, datePickerID) {
  
   var dayModeOptions = {
     format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
     autoclose: true, 
     orientation: 'bottom', 
     startView: "days", 
     minViewMode: "days"         
   };
   var monthModeOptions = {
     format: "mm/yyyy",
     autoclose: true, 
     orientation: 'bottom', 
     startView: "months", 
     minViewMode: "months"         
   };   
   var yearModeOptions = {
     format: "yyyy",
     autoclose: true, 
     orientation: 'bottom', 
     startView: "years", 
     minViewMode: "years"         
   };   
   
   // Destroy & re-initalize with specified Mode Options for ID-specified control
   $(datePickerID).datepicker("destroy");
   if (type == 'day') // Day Mode initialization
    $(datePickerID).datepicker(dayModeOptions);
   else if (type == 'month') // Month Mode initialization 
    $(datePickerID).datepicker(monthModeOptions);
   else // Year Mode initialization
    $(datePickerID).datepicker(yearModeOptions);    
}

$(document).ready(function() {

      // Initialize with initial Mode Options
   $('#combined').datepicker({
     format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
     autoclose: true, 
     orientation: 'bottom', 
     startView: "days", 
     minViewMode: "days"     
   }).on('change', function (ev) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
   });
   
      // Handle radio buttons
   $('input[name=mode]').change(function(){
    // Hide any current DatePicker and erase text box value
    $('#combined').datepicker('hide');
    $('#combined').val('');
    
    var value = $( 'input[name=mode]:checked' ).val();
    if (value == 'day') {
     setDatePicker('day', '#combined');
    } else if (value == 'month') {
     setDatePicker('month', '#combined');
    } else {
     setDatePicker('year', '#combined');
    }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="">
   <input type="radio" id="dayMode" name="mode" value="day" checked> <label for="dayMode">Day</label>  
   <input type="radio" id="monthMode" name="mode" value="month"> <label for="monthMode">Month</label>  
   <input type="radio" id="yearMode" name="mode" value="year"> <label for="yearMode">Year</label>  
</div> 

COMBINED Picker: <input id="combined" placeholder="Depends on radiobutton" style="width:250px"> <br/>
```